# JIRA 30 day summary more issues resolved than created

Tags: jira

In JIRA 4.4, the 30 day summary sometimes shows more issues being resolved than created. I was originally assuming that this chart was cumulative, which means that this should never happen. It seems my team resolves more issues than we create (I wish we were that productive!)

It also doesn't make sense that these are daily totals because in the chart below there is no way 20 issues were created today.

Any ideas? I googled around and couldn't find anything.

[image: Impossible?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chart is cumulative, but only last 30 days are considered. It is possible to solve more issues then was created in amount of time.

Comment: OK, so for each day it's the total issues created/resolved from 30 days prior? i.e. Dec 5th has 17 issues resolved and 15 created since ... Nov 5th? It's on a rolling basis?

Comment: The chart doesn't show how many issues you have in backlog. From a management perspective it's worth knowing if you are creating a greater backlog as you go along. If you have 1 under very moth, you would build your backlog so that you'd have 12 issues at the end of the year.